# Loop through table while records keep getting added to the table

Tags: t-sql, ssis, file-copying, sql-server-2019, ssis-2019

I have a table (`FilesToCopy`) with a list of filenames.

| id | filename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | c:\temp\file1.txt |
| 2 | c:\temp\file2.txt |
| 3 | c:\temp\file2.txt |

One by one the files get copied to another location (eg `c:\test`).
I can loop through this table easy enough to execute a copy command for each file.
That is just an Execute SQL Task reading the table, putting the results in an object variable, followed by a For Each container.

But what if, during the execution of the for each loop, records get added to the table `FilesToCopy` ?

Imagine that **during the for each loop** the file c:\temp\file99.txt gets added to the table `FilesToCopy`

| id | filename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | c:\temp\file1.txt |
| 2 | c:\temp\file2.txt |
| 3 | c:\temp\file2.txt |
| 99 | c:\temp\file99.txt |

Can I somehow tell the for each loop that it also has to copy the file c:\temp\file99.txt even though the file was not there at the beginning of the loop?

So the effect would be:

1. table `FilesToCopy` is read, a loop is started.
2. `c:\temp\file1.txt` is copied to `c:\test`
3. The record for  `c:\temp\file1.txt` is deleted from the table `FilesToCopy`
4. `c:\temp\file2.txt` is copied to `c:\test`
5. The record for  `c:\temp\file2.txt` is deleted from the table `FilesToCopy`
6. In the meanwhile `c:\temp\file99.txt` is added to the table `FilesToCopy`
7. `c:\temp\file3.txt` is copied to `c:\test`
8. The record for  `c:\temp\file3.txt` is deleted from the table `FilesToCopy`
9. `c:\temp\file99.txt` is copied to `c:\test`
10. The record for  `c:\temp\file99.txt` is deleted from the table `FilesToCopy`
11. Loop ends when there are no more records in table `FilesToCopy`

So what I would like to do do is somehow refresh the list that was fed to the loop when it started.

I hope this is clear.

Comment: Seems like a `foreach` container is what you want then. If you ask for the data (presumably with a Transact-SQL task) then that data is then in the object and you're working with that data. Perhaps you should be getting rows one by one, and marking them as "completed" once you've done the task. Then if rows are added, or removed, you'd process them accordingly.

Comment: but the object doesn't change once it is filled by the object task, does it? So even though the table has new records, the object wouldn't know about that? Or am I thinking wrong here?

Comment: This is why I said row by row, not all the rows.

Comment: ahhh! I think I get what you mean Thanx again for putting me on the right path (again), learning a lot from you.

Comment: I just noticed I typod *isn't*, apologies. That should have been *"Seems like a Foreach Loop container **isn't** what you want then."* Instead you want just want a For Loop container.

Comment: @Larnu I solved it using a FOR loop which updates the transferlist, using an IsProcessed column. If you put in an answer I will award you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a do while loop instead.

Have a variable called moreToProcess data type boolean.

Set the value before entering the loop using execute SQL statement based on count > 0

First step in the loop is to get a record to process using exec SQL.

Before exiting loop rerun the SQL to reset the variable.

Set to loop while moreToProcess is true.

Comment: Also, I would recommend an isProcessed column in table data type bit default 0. And instead of deleting, I would mark this column 1 (true). This allows you to see why you did something. It would also be nice to have a LoadTimeStamp defaulted to getdate() on load.

Comment: Guessing that you mean the For loop when talking about a Do While, this put me on the right track

Comment: I guess your right. It is technically called a for loop in SSIS, but in most languages a FOR loop is a known number of loops to run ( FOR i = 1 to 10, for example) and a WHILE loop is for an unknown number of loops while a condition holds true. SSIS wraps both structures into one object.